# Scikit-Optimize how to save convergence plot to file

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I have implemented Bayesian Optimisation using Scikit-Optimize library and want to save some plots after the run. I try with the following code:

```
res = gp_minimize(objective, space, n_calls = 10, acq_func="EI", verbose = True)
print(res.x)
print(res.fun)
ax1 = plot_objective(res)
ax1.savefig("objective.png")
```

But I get error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'savefig'
```

I have looked in various places for examples on how to do this but all I come across is people doing stuff like:

```
_ = plot_objective(forest_res)
```

and showing the resulting plot but this doesn't show how they saved it.

Comment: So *what **is*** `plot_objective`? Also see [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving the current plot using `matplotlib.pyplot`, (which could be imported as `plt`) is done as

```
plt.savefig("filename.png")
```

If you want to save the specific figure which is created by a function returning a numpy array of axes,

```
axes = func(...)
axes.flatten()[0].figure.savefig("filename.png")
```